# Delegate pointing to multiple function with different signatures

Tags: c#, delegates

How can a single delegate point to multiple function which will have different signature?

suppose i have a two functions whose signature is different.

```
private int Add(int x,int y)
{
   return (x+y);
}

private int MultiplyByTwo(int x)
{
   return (x*2);
}
```

please tell me is it possible with single delegate to point Add & multiple two different function at a time and function will call according to argument.

please discuss with code and also tell me how to perform the same job with func<> delegate.

thanks

Comment: Why would you want to do that? It doesn't make sense...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is not possible. The point of a delegate is to act as a strongly typed function pointer (loosely put), and nor will the runtime do any guessing as to what should be called depending on the parameters. If that is the type of functionality you are looking for, you might be interested in the `dynamic` keyword in C# 4.

All delegates inherit from a common delegate called `Delegate`, if that is the functionality you are looking for.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Delegate method1 = new Action<string>(PrintOneString);
    Delegate method2 = new Action<string, string>(PrintTwoString);
    method1.DynamicInvoke("Hello");
    method2.DynamicInvoke("Hello", "Goodbye");
}

public static void PrintOneString(string str)
{
    Console.WriteLine(str);
}

public static void PrintTwoString(string str1, string str2)
{
    Console.WriteLine(str1);
    Console.WriteLine(str2);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but is it possible that if two function signature is same then ? please explain. i think there is multicast delegate.

Comment: @Thomas - It is not possible.  Do some research into the dynamic keyword and come back with what you have actually attempted.

Answer (score 3):

As the others already said, the signature of those methods are different. You can map the `Add` method to a `Func<int, int, int>` delegate:

```
Func<int, int, int> add = calculator.Add;
```

And you can map the `MultiplyByTo` method to a `Func<int, int>` delegate:

```
Func<int, int> multiply = calculator.MultiplyByTo;
```

You can map the `Add` method to a `Func<int, int>` delegate, but you need to fill in the missing argument:

```
Func<int, int> add5 = x => calculator.Add(x, 5);
```

Answer (score 2):

Delegates are built to be strongly typed therefore you cannot achieve what you want by using them

You might should consider **dynamic** (.net 4.0)

-or-

using **reflection**. You could store the method name in a string variable and then invoke the method name by reflection.

Hope it helps